# how can I get ExceptionTranslationFilter's BeanDefinition created by <http>

Tags: spring-security

everyone:

How can I get `ExceptionTranslationFilter`'s `BeanDefinition` created by  in 3.0.x and 3.1.x? I want to reuse its `PropertyValue` of `BeanDefinition` (**accessDeniedHandler** and **authenticationEntryPoint**). I found that I cannot get it from `DefaultListableBeanFactory` by bean name or class, it seems that ExceptionTranslationFilter's BeanDefinition is not registered.

Other filter like `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`, it has a bean name :**org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0**. But `ExceptionTranslationFilter` doesn't have one.

The only way I found is to search in filterChainProxy's properties iteratively, is there any better way?

what I do in psuedo code:

```
BeanDefinitionBuilder builder = 
    BeanDefinitionBuilder.rootBeanDefinition(MyExceptionFilter.class);
RootBeanDefinition exceptionTranslationFilter = getExceptionTranslationFilterBeanDefinition();     
PropertyValue accessDeniedHandler = exceptionTranslationFilter.getPropertyValues().getPropertyValue("accessDeniedHandler");
Object handler = (RootBeanDefinition) accessDeniedHandler.getValue();
builder.addPropertyValue("accessDeniedHandler", handler);
beanDefinitionRegistry.registerBeanDefinition("myFilter", builder.getBeanDefinition());
```

So, the real problem is **what is the best way to get core filter ExceptionTranslation's accesDeniedHandler `BeanDefinition`**

Comment: What property exactly you want to get? `ExceptionTranslationFilter` itself seems to be internal for Spring Security for some reason.

Comment: I am doing an integration work. I want to register a custom BeanDefinition programmatically which uses same PropertyValue. I need ExceptionTranslationFilte's **accessDeniedHandler** and **authenticationEntryPoint**.

Comment: I found I can get `ExceptionTranslationFilter` by getting filter chain bean with name **org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFi lterChain#0**.
Is this bean name's naming rule an internal spec in Spring? Will this rule be overridden by user configuration?
I just want to guarantee I can always get this bean in 3.0.x and 3.1.x through this way, and it's not fragile. thanks.

Comment: Playing with internals is never good as they can change in the future.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because [you can't change `ExceptionTranslationFilter` implementation or have access to it](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#nsa-http):

> Each `<http>` namespace block always creates an
>   `SecurityContextPersistenceFilter`, an `ExceptionTranslationFilter`
>   and a `FilterSecurityInterceptor`. These are fixed and cannot be
>   replaced with alternatives.

you should either use "traditional" bean `FilterChainProxy` (using the namespace proxy's name "springSecurityFilterChain") or gain access to `ExceptionTranslationFilter`'s properties by defining them explicitely and referencing them in `<http>`:

```
<http entry-point-ref="authenticationEntryPoint">
  <access-denied-handler ref="accessDeniedHandler" />
  <!-- other options -->
</http>

<bean:bean id="authenticationEntryPoint" 
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
  <bean:property name="loginFormUrl" value="/login.htm"/>
</bean:bean>

<bean:bean id="accessDeniedHandler"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.access.AccessDeniedHandlerImpl">
  <bean:property name="errorPage" value="/accessDenied.htm" />
</bean:bean>
```

`AuthenticationEntryPoint` implementation, according to docs, is *set depending on which authentication mechanisms have been configured*, so pick one you'll need.

Comment: I want to register a `BeanDefinition` of my custom exception filter, and my exception filter uses same `PropertyValue` of "accessDeniedHandler". I am not going to replace it. I'll attach a psuedo code later.
`

Comment: From [`ExceptionTranslationFilter`'s docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/access/ExceptionTranslationFilter.html): _By default the filter will use AccessDeniedHandlerImpl._ so you're not **replacing** `accessDeniedHandler` but explicitely defining it to have access to it in other beans / code - that's the way you do it. The same is with `authenticationEntryPoint` but its implementation depends on other filter i.e. <form-login>` uses `LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint`.

Comment: And if you **really** want to define custom `ExceptionTranslationFilter` (which, according to Spring Security guys isn't necessary, because they fixed it), [define `FilterChainProxy` by hand like described in docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#filter-chain-proxy) and you'll be able to probide `ExceptionTranslationFilter` subclass.

Comment: I think it works. But I give up to create a `BeanDefinition` by my own finally. Because I don't know much about spring security. I just need to design a maintainence patch. But thanks for your help.